# Will solder layer of via short a trace?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, rf

As the picture shows I have a via fence with one of the vias solder layer touching a trace. Will this short the trace or do I only need to worry about the via hole as there is no soldering on that mask.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't tell without dimensions and ultimately is up to the tolerances of your PCB fab if they can make traces that close and your own soldering ability.

Comment: What does the grey area around pads represent? Either you're not using the default colour scheme, or something is wrong with the footprints of the components.

Comment: The grey area of the components is the top paste, the grey area via hole im not sure. Im using simple vias, but when selecting top-middle-bottom or full stack the grey around the via hole disappears.

Comment: the grey can't be paste, this is outside the pad...The grey is probably mask

Comment: so then do I have a greater problem of my paste being larger than the pads? Because it is most definitely paste, check the screenshot of my layer configuration

Comment: Why are you putting solder paste on your vias?

Comment: There are two shades of grey.  I think the darker is the one he is saying is the paste layer.

Comment: yes, the darker is the paste. I am not sure what the lighter grey area is on the via, hence my question.

Comment: I use KiCad and I can select which layers are on or off, they are color coded so you can find which one you are questioning, click the button and if it turns off read its label if not try another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would only be a problem if copper is touching copper (and if you run a Design Rule Check (DRC) then it will make sure that copper doesn't touch (unless it's the same net name, in that case you intended it to connect)

The solder paste layer does extend to far beyond the footprints (unless you intended to do that), you may have issues manufacturing an assembled PCB or if you have a solder paste stencil produced. The solder paste layer normally extends to the only the pad for most parts.

[image]